# Django Local module import is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── LMS
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── VENV
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   ├── images
│   └── js
├── courses
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── fields.py
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── templatetags
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── media
│   ├── course_images
│   ├── files
│   └── images
├── templates
│   └── base.html
└── users
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── templates
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Now I'm trying to import `courses.models.Course` in my `users.models` in the following way:

```
from courses.models import Course
```

> **Update: Here is the `courses.models`**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('title',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Course(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account,
                              related_name='courses_created',
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,
                                related_name='courses',
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    overview = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    course_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='course_images/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

but its giving an error as:

```
from courses.models import Course
ImportError: cannot import name 'Course' from 'courses.models'
(/Users/abdul/PycharmProjects/LMS/courses/models.py)
```

Comment: Please show your `courses.models` file

Comment: @GProst  Added `courses.models`

Comment: I believe you didnt show imports in courses.models file. Please show the file completely